# I want to open a link in several browsers simultaneously for testing

Tags: shell, browser, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to open for example "localhost/MySite" in IE9, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari simultaneously for QA testing.

I was thinking a batch file of some sort would be an effective way of doing this.

i.e. double click "test.bat" and a command line comes up with a query "Website to test: ".  I enter in "localhost/MySite", and the batch file opens all of these browsers and goes to that site.

I'm not sure if this is possible, as I've not found anything on the topic, but it would be very useful for me!  Always good to save a bit of time. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
setlocal
set /p url=Website to test:
start chrome %url%
start firefox %url%
start iexplore %url%
start opera %url%
start safari %url%
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I did! Problem is you have to have all of those in your PATH environment variable normally.  I'm posting the full answer above, and I upvoted yours. Thanks!

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 I definitely don't have `iexplore` in my `PATH`. (In fact, I don't have any of the others in my `PATH` either, but that's beyond the scope of this comment.)

Comment: Hehe, yeah.  I wanted a generic script I could give to the QA team.  I suppose I could have specified that :P  I ended up using something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do something like this in a batch script:

```
cd "/path/to/file1"
start program1.exe

cd "/path/to/file2"
start program2.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working great:

```
set /p url= [Desired URL to test?]

if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" %url%&
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %url%&
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Opera\opera.exe" start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Opera\opera.exe" %url%&
if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Safari\Safari.exe" start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Safari\Safari.exe" %url%&
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" start "" "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %url%&
```